# Check for .NET 4.5 full install - which property?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

How do I check for a full .net 4.5 install?

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm

has a list of all properties but stops at 4.0.

The open issues list has a nice Topic "add documentation for the new properties" which helne to USE them.

Anyone knows the property Name for a full 4.5 install?

Comment: Setup development *IS* development.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answering myself - as documentation was updated also:

NETFRAMEWORK45

More concrete:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>

<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.5. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45]]>
</Condition>
```

Comment: I tried that, but then after more reading, realized I NEEDED to add a reference to the WixNetFxExtension.dll  (C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin\\WixNetFxExtension.dll )

Comment: Details: "Add the -ext <path to WixNetfxExtension.dll> command line parameter when calling light.exe to include the WixNetfxExtension in the MSI linking process."